# How to point a learn more link dircetly to a tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css

not sure how to explain my problem here. Sorry if this question been duplicated. Here is a picture that explained what I am trying to do, but I have no idea to figure it out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgogA.png

I've heard that this should open many .html file, but I think this can be solve using javascript. Your answer much appreciated!

Comment: you can compile specific `scss` files like tabs from popular plugins like bootstrap, materialize, foundation and use them.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, what you are trying to do is an SPA - Single Page Application.

This could be done in lots of ways, I personally prefer to use AngularJS.

I hope this answered your question, good luck :)

Comment: Do you have any link to refer? :)

Comment: @R3y For the basics of AngularJS you can go to their [website](https://angularjs.org/). For basic routing in Ajgular see [this](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/spa#/searchtable) page.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of plugins that can do this, or just make it yourself.

But if you're looking for ajax tabs, checkout:
https://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#ajax-tabs
which will load html files on different tabs.

Here's an example which doesn't use ajax, but only page content:
https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK

*index.html*

```
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

</div><!-- container -->
```

style.css

```
body{
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
    line-height: 1.6
}
.container{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li{
    background: none;
    color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current{
    background: #ededed;
    color: #222;
}

.tab-content{
    display: none;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current{
    display: inherit;
}
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})
```